# How to check if an IP address is from a particular network/netmask in Java?

Tags: java, networking, ip

I need to determine if given IP address is from some special network in order to authenticate automatically.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) has `org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils` that appears to satisfy your needs.  It looks like you do something like this:

```
SubnetInfo subnet = (new SubnetUtils("10.10.10.0", "255.255.255.128")).getInfo();
boolean test = subnet.isInRange("10.10.10.10");
```

Note, as [carson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25343/carson) points out, that Apache Commons Net has [a bug](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-issues/200902.mbox/%3C2039253761.1233796319684.JavaMail.jira@brutus%3E) that prevents it from giving the correct answer in some cases.  Carson suggests using the SVN version to avoid this bug.

Comment: Be careful using this. There is a bug that will keep it from working correctly. You may want to pull it out of SVN.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-issues/200902.mbox/%3C2039253761.1233796319684.JavaMail.jira@brutus%3E

Comment: @carson: Thanks for the warning.  I edited my answer to include this information.

Comment: doesn't look like this supports IPv6 either

Answer (score 58):

### Option 1:

Use [`spring-security-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web)'s [IpAddressMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/IpAddressMatcher.html#matches(java.lang.String)). Unlike Apache Commons Net, it supports both ipv4 and ipv6.

```
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.IpAddressMatcher;
...

private void checkIpMatch() {
    matches("192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.1"); // true
    matches("192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.0/32"); // false
    matches("192.168.2.5", "192.168.2.0/24"); // true
    matches("92.168.2.1", "fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1/120"); // false
    matches("fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:11", "fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1/120"); // true
    matches("fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:11", "fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1/128"); // false
    matches("fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:11", "192.168.2.0/32"); // false
}

private boolean matches(String ip, String subnet) {
    IpAddressMatcher ipAddressMatcher = new IpAddressMatcher(subnet);
    return ipAddressMatcher.matches(ip);
}
```

---

### Option 2 (a lightweight solution!):

*The code in previous part works perfectly fine* but it needs `spring-security-web` to be included.

If you are not willing to include Spring framework in your project, you may use this class which is a slightly modified version of the [original class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/IpAddressMatcher.java) from Spring, so that it has no non-JRE dependencies.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2002-2019 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Matches a request based on IP Address or subnet mask matching against the remote
 * address.
 * <p>
 * Both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses are supported, but a matcher which is configured with an
 * IPv4 address will never match a request which returns an IPv6 address, and vice-versa.
 *
 * @author Luke Taylor
 * @since 3.0.2
 * 
 * Slightly modified by omidzk to have zero dependency to any frameworks other than the JRE.
 */
public final class IpAddressMatcher {
    private final int nMaskBits;
    private final InetAddress requiredAddress;

    /**
     * Takes a specific IP address or a range specified using the IP/Netmask (e.g.
     * 192.168.1.0/24 or 202.24.0.0/14).
     *
     * @param ipAddress the address or range of addresses from which the request must
     * come.
     */
    public IpAddressMatcher(String ipAddress) {

        if (ipAddress.indexOf('/') > 0) {
            String[] addressAndMask = ipAddress.split("/");
            ipAddress = addressAndMask[0];
            nMaskBits = Integer.parseInt(addressAndMask[1]);
        }
        else {
            nMaskBits = -1;
        }
        requiredAddress = parseAddress(ipAddress);
        assert  (requiredAddress.getAddress().length * 8 >= nMaskBits) :
                String.format("IP address %s is too short for bitmask of length %d",
                        ipAddress, nMaskBits);
    }

    public boolean matches(String address) {
        InetAddress remoteAddress = parseAddress(address);

        if (!requiredAddress.getClass().equals(remoteAddress.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (nMaskBits < 0) {
            return remoteAddress.equals(requiredAddress);
        }

        byte[] remAddr = remoteAddress.getAddress();
        byte[] reqAddr = requiredAddress.getAddress();

        int nMaskFullBytes = nMaskBits / 8;
        byte finalByte = (byte) (0xFF00 >> (nMaskBits & 0x07));

        // System.out.println("Mask is " + new sun.misc.HexDumpEncoder().encode(mask));

        for (int i = 0; i < nMaskFullBytes; i++) {
            if (remAddr[i] != reqAddr[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (finalByte != 0) {
            return (remAddr[nMaskFullBytes] & finalByte) == (reqAddr[nMaskFullBytes] & finalByte);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private InetAddress parseAddress(String address) {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getByName(address);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to parse address" + address, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTICE**: Notice that for using this option, it's your responsibility to carefully examine the [license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) to make sure by using this code, you are not in violation of any terms mandated by the aforementioned license. (Of course publishing this code to Stackoverflow.com by me is not a violation.)

Answer (score 21):

You can also try the following for IPv4, or the equivalent for IPv6.
NOTE: The IP is the address as a 32-bit `int`

```
boolean inSubnet = (ip & netmask) == (subnet & netmask);
```

or shorter

```
boolean inSubnet = (ip ^ subnet) & netmask == 0;
```

Comment: Are ip and netmask ints or longs?

Comment: 32-bit addresses, IPv4, are ints.  I suspect IPv6 are 64-bit values, but I haven't used hem myself

Comment: IPv6 are 128-bit values (16 bytes), hence they can't be stored on a single long

Comment: So, in the omitted prologue you convert IPv4 addresses and the network mask to integers

Answer (score 12):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will do this in a polymorphic manner for both IPv4 and IPv6 and handles subnets.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Example code:

```
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.3");
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.5");
contains("1::/64", "1::1");
contains("1::/64", "2::1");
contains("1::3-4:5-6", "1::4:5");       
contains("1-2::/64", "2::");
contains("bla", "foo");

static void contains(String network, String address) {
    IPAddressString one = new IPAddressString(network);
    IPAddressString two = new IPAddressString(address);
    System.out.println(one +  " contains " + two + " " + one.contains(two));
}
```

Output:

```
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.3 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.5 false
1::/64 contains 1::1 true
1::/64 contains 2::1 false
1::3-4:5-6 contains 1::4:5 true
1-2::/64 contains 2:: true
bla contains foo false
```

Comment: Excellent library! I really like how easy to use it is and that it works in the vast majority of cases. It does not work correctly for the IPv5 cases stated in @Omid's response though. Could you incorporate that functionality please?

Comment: The difference is intentional and is simply a difference in interpretation and in library implementation, see https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress/issues/40

Answer (score 6):

here is an Version that works with IPv4 and IPv6 one with Prefix and one with Network Mask.

```
/**
 * Check if IP is within an Subnet defined by Network Address and Network Mask
 * @param  ip
 * @param  net
 * @param  mask
 * @return
 */
public static final boolean isIpInSubnet(final String ip, final String net, final int prefix) {
    try {
        final byte[] ipBin   = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(ip  ).getAddress();
        final byte[] netBin  = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(net ).getAddress();
        if(ipBin.length  != netBin.length ) return false;
        int p = prefix;
        int i = 0;
        while(p>=8) { if(ipBin[i] != netBin[i] ) return false; ++i; p-=8; }
        final int m = (65280 >> p) & 255;
        if((ipBin[i] & m) != (netBin[i]&m) ) return false;

        return true;
    } catch(final Throwable t) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check if IP is within an Subnet defined by Network Address and Network Mask
 * @param  ip
 * @param  net
 * @param  mask
 * @return
 */
public static final boolean isIpInSubnet(final String ip, final String net, final String mask) {
    try {
        final byte[] ipBin   = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(ip  ).getAddress();
        final byte[] netBin  = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(net ).getAddress();
        final byte[] maskBin = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(mask).getAddress();
        if(ipBin.length  != netBin.length ) return false;
        if(netBin.length != maskBin.length) return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < ipBin.length; ++i) if((ipBin[i] & maskBin[i]) != (netBin[i] & maskBin[i])) return false;
        return true;
    } catch(final Throwable t) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old question, but I stumbled upon this when I was looking to solve the same problem.

There is [commons-ip-math](https://github.com/jgonian/commons-ip-math) library that I believe does a very good job. Please note that as of May 2019, there hasn't been any updates to the library (Could be that its already very mature library). Its available on [maven-central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.jgonian/commons-ip-math/1.32/jar)

It supports working with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Their brief documentation has examples on how you can check if an address is in a specific range for [IPv4](https://github.com/jgonian/commons-ip-math#ipv4-addresses) and [IPv6](https://github.com/jgonian/commons-ip-math#ipv6-addresses)

Example for IPv4 range checking:

```
        String input1 = "192.168.1.0";
        Ipv4 ipv41 = Ipv4.parse(input1);

        // Using CIDR notation to specify the networkID and netmask
        Ipv4Range range = Ipv4Range.parse("192.168.0.0/24");
        boolean result = range.contains(ipv41);
        System.out.println(result); //false

        String input2 = "192.168.0.251";
        Ipv4 ipv42 = Ipv4.parse(input2);

        // Specifying the range with a start and end.
        Ipv4 start = Ipv4.of("192.168.0.0");
        Ipv4 end = Ipv4.of("192.168.0.255");
        range = Ipv4Range.from(start).to(end);

        result = range.contains(ipv42); //true
        System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check An IP in a subnet, I used isInRange method in SubnetUtils class. But this method have a bug that if your subnet was X, every IP address that lower than X, isInRange return true. For example if your subnet was 10.10.30.0/24 and you want to check 10.10.20.5, this method return true. To deal with this bug I used below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String list = "10.10.20.0/24";
    String IP1 = "10.10.20.5";
    String IP2 = "10.10.30.5";
    SubnetUtils  subnet = new SubnetUtils(list);
    SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo subnetInfo = subnet.getInfo();
    if(MyisInRange(subnetInfo , IP1) == true)
       System.out.println("True");
    else 
       System.out.println("False");
    if(MyisInRange(subnetInfo , IP2) == true)
       System.out.println("True");
    else
       System.out.println("False");
}

private boolean MyisInRange(SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo info, String Addr )
{
    int address = info.asInteger( Addr );
    int low = info.asInteger( info.getLowAddress() );
    int high = info.asInteger( info.getHighAddress() );
    return low <= address && address <= high;
}
```

Comment: SubnetUtils seems to be that Apache Common class

Answer (score 0):

Building on Peter Lawrey's answer and with the goal of using the simplest option with 0 dependencies with both IPv4 and IPv6 support, the following function can be used

```
/**
   * Checks if the provided IP address is part of the provided subnet.
   *
   * @param ip     ip address in string format. Supports both IPv4 and IPv6
   * @param subnet subnet address in cidr format (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24)
   * @return
   * @throws UnknownHostException
   */
  public boolean ipInSubnet(String ip, String subnet) throws UnknownHostException {
    int maskSize = Integer.parseInt(subnet.split("/")[1]);
    final InetAddress subnetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(subnet.split("/")[0]);
    final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    int maxMaskSize = subnetAddress instanceof Inet4Address ? 32 : 128;
    final BigInteger maskBits = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(maskSize).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).shiftLeft(maxMaskSize - maskSize);
    return new BigInteger(address.getAddress()).xor(new BigInteger(subnetAddress.getAddress())).and(maskBits).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
  }
```