# How to check the IP range by java matcher regular expression

Tags: java, regex

My Current Regular Expression for checking the ip range between: `178.2.1.1 to 178.2.1.254`  is as follow:

`178.2.1.1.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$`

Is there any other better expression way to check that.

Comment: Define 'between'. What you have specified is an upper limit followed by a lower limit. But regular expressions are entirely the wrong tool for this. You should just use the IP addresses themselves as 32-bit integers, or byte arrays, and do it arithmetically.

Comment: The given regex totally doesn't match the requested range.

Comment: What do you mean with "between"? The second ip is - numerically speaking - lower than the first.

Comment: I wonder why, when there's a [perfectly established way of dealing with IP ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation), people still insist on regular expressions. In Java you can use the [Apache Commons implementation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html) for example.

Comment: @biziclop: the articles means that the first *i* bits are significant. Here `255` and `0` are excluded (yeah I know these are special ones), but lets say one wishes an ip to be between `178.2.8.14` and `194.45.2.41` for some strange reason, you cannot perform this with such mask.

Comment: @biziclop Regex tend to be used for anything *but* what they are made for.

Comment: @CommuSoft The range you specified corresponds to `178.2.8.14/31,178.2.8.16/28,178.2.8.32/29,178.2.8.40/31` in CIDR notation. But yes, with arbitrary ranges CIDR isn't that straightforward.

Comment: @biziclop: I'm not convincted the comma is part of the standard. If one reads the specs on the Wiki page it says an IP address with a slash (`/`) and a routing prefix. Here you specify multiple CIDRs. Making checking computationally harder.

Comment: @CommuSoft Okay, my main point really was to not use regular expressions, and I think we agree on that.

Comment: @biziclop: sure. I've also added your subnet suggestion in the answer. It was a valuable contribution. The only point is that CIDR is sometimes not expressive enough.

Answer (score 5):

## Regular expression

Assuming you want to match all IP adresses between `178.2.1.1` and `178.2.1.254` (with `178` instead of `1`), you can use the following regex:

```
^178\.2\.1\.([1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4])$
```

Dropping the last `1.`, using escapes for the dots (`\.`) and using the anchor in the front of the regex (`^`).

## Bounds checking with a library

But **that will not suffice** in general. Most IP parsers allow for instance to specify an IP as `127.00.00.01`, etc. Furthermore don't forget that nowadays people move to IPv6 which has a completely different syntax. You better do the parsing to an `InetAddress` in Java as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5571816/67579). In case it is an IPv4, you can then simply perform bound checks, like is partly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209760/validate-an-ip-address-with-mask):

```
String       s = "178.2.1.178";
Inet4Address a = (Inet4Address) InetAddress.getByName(s);
byte[]       b = a.getAddress();
int          ip = ((b[0] & 0xFF) << 24) |
                  ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                  ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8)  |
                  ((b[3] & 0xFF) << 0);
int low =  0xb2020101; //equivalent of 178.2.1.1
int high = 0xb20201fe; //equivalent of 178.2.1.254
if(low <= ip && ip <= high) {
    //matches bounds
} else {
    //doesn't match bounds
}
```

Or as @IanMcLaird suggests, one better uses a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger addr = new BigInteger(InetAddress.getByName("178.2.1.178").getAddress());
BigInteger low = new BigInteger(InetAddress.getByName("178.2.1.1").getAddress());
BigInteger high = new BigInteger(InetAddress.getByName("178.2.1.254").getAddress());
if(low.compareTo(addr) <= 0 && addr.compareTo(high) <= 0) {
    //in range
} else {
    //not in range
}
```

## Subnets

Please note you can describe the range of your IP with `178.2.1.0/24` since `.0` and `.255` are special cases, it means the last byte is not significant. In such case we're talking about a *subnet* and - as @biziclop says - you can use [these Apache utils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html).

Comment: I think I'd use a `BigInteger` instead of `int`, since it has the benefit of having an appropriate constructor (which won't require odd-looking bit-shifting operators) *and* has the benefit of being able to handle IPv6 addresses with the same logic.

Comment: @IanMcLaird: indeed, thanks for that suggestion. Furthermore it allows easier conversion towards IPv6. Better?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful with "between" as both IPs can have min/max values. You can do something like:

```
/**
 * check if IP address match pattern
 * 
 * @param pattern
 *            *.*.*.* , 192.168.1.0-255 , *
 * @param address
 *            - 192.168.1.1
 *            address = 10.2.88.12  pattern = *.*.*.*   result: true
 *                address = 10.2.88.12  pattern = *   result: true
 *                address = 10.2.88.12  pattern = 10.2.88.12-13   result: true
 *                address = 10.2.88.12  pattern = 10.2.88.13-125   result: false
 * @return true if address match pattern
 */
public static boolean checkIPMatching(String pattern, String address)
{
    if (pattern.equals("*.*.*.*") || pattern.equals("*"))
      return true;

    String[] mask = pattern.split("\\.");
    String[] ip_address = address.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++)
    {
      if (mask[i].equals("*") || mask[i].equals(ip_address[i]))
        continue;
      else if (mask[i].contains("-"))
      {
        byte min = Byte.parseByte(mask[i].split("-")[0]);
        byte max = Byte.parseByte(mask[i].split("-")[1]);
        byte ip = Byte.parseByte(ip_address[i]);
        if (ip < min || ip > max)
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(Part of [aion-emu package](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/CheckifIPaddressmatchpattern.htm) )

Answer (score 0):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can provide the answer rather easily, as shown in this code example. 
 Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

```
public static boolean check(String addressToCheck) {
    return new IPAddressString("178.2.1.1-254").getAddress().
        contains(new IPAddressString(addressToCheck).getAddress());
}
```