# Best approach to authenticate with a login form for users and without login form for anonymous

Tags: java, authentication, forms-authentication, vaadin

I have to build a web application who shows some data. I will have two kinds of user: register users and anonymous users. Registers users will run the app from the company intranet, and anonymous users will run the app from internet. Registers users will see more data than the anonymous ones.

I need a login form to registers users (to know who is seeing the data), but when an anonymous user will use the application, login form must not show.

In the same web application, the first screen must be a login form, but in some cases the login form must not appear. What is the best way to do that?

I'm using Vaadin (Java framework based on GWT) to develop my app. I think a good way to do that is checking the browser url, but I'm not sure if is the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as McOmghall says. You can get the user's ip by calling:

```
WebBrowser b = (WebBrowser) getMainWindow().getTerminal().
String ip = b.getAddress();
```

or (in your Application class):

```
WebBrowser b = ((WebApplicationContext) getContext()).getBrowser();
String ip = b.getAddress();
```

Then you can use Jakara Commons Net to check if the IP address is in the subnet of your company (for example 192.168.0.0/24):

```
SubnetInfo subnet = (new SubnetUtils("192.168.0.0", "255.255.255.0")).getInfo();
boolean test = subnet.isInRange(ip);
```

Here's [another cool solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/579300/403053) that doesn't require the use of any 3rd party libs.

[Source 1](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/18465)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577363/does-anyone-know-a-java-component-to-check-if-ip-address-is-from-particular-netw)

Answer (score 0):

If you have distinction between extranet and intranet, you should check the origin of the connection by IP. Java provides a way to do this, but I don't know if this is possible with Vaadin.