# Java check if IPv4 or IPv6 address is in a given subnet

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4, subnet

How can I check if an IP address is in a given subnet? I was able to do this by using Apache Commons SubnetUtils ([SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo.isInRange](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo.html)) but it does not support IPv6 yet.

Comment: Commons Net feature request to vote for: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-405

Answer (score 8):

[edazdarevic's CIDRUtils](https://github.com/edazdarevic/CIDRUtils) supports both IPv4 and IPv6. The example does not mention boolean isInRange(String ipAddress), but it is implemented!

Another option is [java-ipv6](http://code.google.com/p/java-ipv6/), but it does not support IPv4 and [requires JDK7](http://janvanbesien.blogspot.nl/2011/10/java-library-for-ipv6.html?showComment=1320401052493#c2242936235506825385).

Answer (score 7):

Use `spring-security-web`'s [IpAddressMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/IpAddressMatcher.html#matches(java.lang.String)). Unlike Apache Commons Net, it supports both ipv4 and ipv6.

```
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.IpAddressMatcher;
...

private void checkIpMatch() {
    matches("192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.1"); // true
    matches("192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.0/32"); // false
    matches("192.168.2.5", "192.168.2.0/24"); // true
    matches("92.168.2.1", "fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1/120"); // false
    matches("fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:11", "fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1/120"); // true
    matches("fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:11", "fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1/128"); // false
    matches("fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:11", "192.168.2.0/32"); // false
}

private boolean matches(String ip, String subnet) {
    IpAddressMatcher ipAddressMatcher = new IpAddressMatcher(subnet);
    return ipAddressMatcher.matches(ip);
}
```

### Remarks

If you're not willing to include Spring in your project, check out my other answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41482123/387048).

Answer (score 2):

[commons-ip-math](https://github.com/jgonian/commons-ip-math) provides support for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Here is how you can check if an IP address is in a given subnet:

```
Ipv4Range.parse("192.168.0.0/24").contains(Ipv4.parse("10.0.0.1")) 
// false

Ipv6Range.parse("2001:db8::/32").contains(Ipv6.parse("2001:db8::4"))
// true
```

*(disclaimer, I'm one of the maintainers of commons-ip-math)*

Answer (score 1):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports both IPv4 and IPv6 in a polymorphic manner and supports subnets, including methods that check for containment of an address or subnet in a containing subnet.  The javadoc is available at the link.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Example code:

```
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.3");
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.5");
contains("1::/64", "1::1");
contains("1::/64", "2::1");
contains("1::3-4:5-6", "1::4:5");       
contains("1-2::/64", "2::");
contains("bla", "foo");

static void contains(String network, String address) {
    IPAddressString one = new IPAddressString(network);
    IPAddressString two = new IPAddressString(address);
    System.out.println(one +  " contains " + two + " " + one.contains(two));
}
```

Output:

```
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.3 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.5 false
1::/64 contains 1::1 true
1::/64 contains 2::1 false
1::3-4:5-6 contains 1::4:5 true
1-2::/64 contains 2:: true
bla contains foo false
```