# Compare a list of Ip Ranges (with CIDR) in Java

Tags: java, ip, range, cidr

I have a list of IP ranges specified with a CIDR. I want to compare the ranges and remove all the ranges which are already included in another one.

Example: I have:

> 10.152.0.0/14
>
> 10.152.2.0/24
>
> 10.153.3.0/24

In the Result only 10.152.0.0/14 should remain, because the other two are already included in that.

I tried with the org.apache.commons.net.util Package, but if im not wrong it can only compare a Range to an Adress and not compare Ranges itself.

Is there any library in Java that can help me compare those ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following link [CIDRUtils](https://github.com/edazdarevic/CIDRUtils). You'll need to do the checks yourself but the method call `isInRange` is implemented (it's not documented). This has also been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025046/java-library-to-check-if-ipv4-or-ipv6-address-is-in-a-given-subnet)

Comment: Okay, this seems  pretty much the same like the `isInRange` from  org.apache.commons.net.util --> SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo. I was hoping there would be a way to compare two Ranges directly.

Comment: Okay, I kind of did it like you suggested. I didn't use CIDRUtils, but as mentioned above the org.apache.commons.net.util package to create an object of each range in my list. After that I checked them manually by comparing the first and the last Ip from each range to all other ranges. I did that with the help of 'isInRange`and `getAllAddresses'. This would not work if ranges could overlap each other, which wasn't the case for me.