# How to check IP and CIDR format in Java effectively?

Tags: java, ip, cidr

I just checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667371/validate-ipv4-address-in-java) for IP checking and this [SubnetUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html) to check CIDR format.

```
private boolean isValidCidrIp(String cidrIp) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    try {
        new SubnetUtils(cidrIp);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

But I really do not want to `import` a package because I want to check a IP and CIDR if I have other choices.

So I came up with this Regx pattern:

`private static final Pattern IP_V4_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            "^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])(/([0-2]?\\d?|3[0-2]))?$");`

But it really seems not good enough, which will include some ugly leading `0` for each field. What's even worse, there will lots of invalid IP addresses.

Have some better ideas?

Comment: According to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html they use `private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})";`

Comment: Also have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025046/java-library-to-check-if-ipv4-or-ipv6-address-is-in-a-given-subnet

Comment: @Scary Thank you so much. Sorry to reply late, I just checked the `Source Code`, I think the Regx I enclosed is good now. Seems more robust.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern cidrPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,3})");

System.out.println(cidrPattern.matcher("192.168.30.0/24").matches());
System.out.println(cidrPattern.matcher("192.168.30.160").matches());
```

Comment: This will not work for invalid ip addresses.

999.999.999.999/999 will also be deemed valid by this regex, and we all know this is not a valid ip v4 address.